# Inventory Management system for managing equipments

Tags: windows

Any recommendations for an Inventory/stock management software

It will be used tot track equipments and spare parts in a company warehouse

To be intalled on a server and assessed by other clients

Comment: Do you meant "accessed" by other clients? (or "assessed"?)